# How .Net Core app can authenticate from Expressjs session?

Tags: c#, node.js, authentication, asp.net-core, single-sign-on

The first app is developed on Expressjs.
Authentication modules:

```
passport.js
express-session
cookie-parser
connect-mongo
```

session middleware

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'kkkjfdfdf787dfdfdf7SSDSf7787asXZ',
    store: new MongoStore({ url: mongoData.url, mongoOptions: {useUnifiedTopology: true}}),
    name: 'nature_app',
    rolling: true,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
      maxAge: process.env.MAX_SESS_AGE_SEC * 1000
    }
  })
)
```

Mongodb session collection after login gets data:

```
{
    "_id" : "OtNPaWfyE6tpkfpIWh-m7XvCAp3No-JN",
    "expires" : ISODate("2019-09-21T16:04:18.732+03:00"),
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":3600000,\"expires\":\"2019-09-21T13:04:18.732Z\",\"secure\":false,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"csrfSecret\":\"rz_etmj7859KAC0OQRCPiyRF\",\"flash\":{},\"passport\":{\"user\":3143}}"
}
```

Cookie (nature_app) id:

```
s%3AOtNPaWfyE6tpkfpIWh-m7XvCAp3No-JN.8Yy2SKhGyt3NCEdka90JmEyrdphPas1yt6OHabDeqis
```

Now I'm developing the second app - admin panel with .Net Core 3, EntityFramework. Both apps will be into same domain. The first app: wow-nature.com, the second: wow-nature.com/admin.
 If user was login into Expressjs app, and he clicked on admin panel link - .Net Core has to automatically login (like SSO). Admin panel won't have login panel.

I found three choices, but I doubt for security reasons:

1. .Net Core has to read Expressjs cookie id and check it in MongoDb. If a session valid - .Net Core will authenticate session. After it .Net Core has to regenerate session id. But my cookie id and mongodb id are different:

```
s%3AOtNPaWfyE6tpkfpIWh-m7XvCAp3No-JN.8Yy2SKhGyt3NCEdka90JmEyrdphPas1yt6OHabDeqis != OtNPaWfyE6tpkfpIWh-m7XvCAp3No-JN
```

And - is this method safe?

2. [Jwt](https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/json-web-token-jwt-the-right-way-of-implementing-with-node-js-65b8915d550e). I don't know how .Net Core works with web tokens.  I read about [authencation users from Laravel to Nodejs](https://m.dotdev.co/authenticate-laravel-5-user-account-in-nodejs-socket-io-using-json-web-tokens-jwt-f74009d612f8). In other places I read security doubts about it.
3. [Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/create-a-simple-and-secure-node-express-app/).

I'm confused. Sorry, I'm beginner in this situation.

What way .Net Core app authenticate from  Expressjs app is more secure?
What are best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from Asp.Net Core developer - it's not possible. For security reason we have not access to .Net core cookie modification. 
So, I recreated app:

1. Main authentication with IdentityServer (OpenId).
2. Expressjs is client.
3. Other .Net Core app is client too.

Better way is to work by standard. No need reinvent bicycle.